# Преобразование даты

Tags: oracle, java

Требуется передать дату в таблицу в формате ‘дд.мм.гггг’, чтобы при этом она оставалась датой, а не стрингом и при сортировке вела себя как положено дате. 
Подскажите на каком этапе я лажанулся?

В Оракле:
select  to_char(date,'dd.mm.yyyy') дата from table

В модели таблицы:

```
if ((rst.getMetaData().getColumnTypeName(i).equals("VARCHAR2"))
        & (rst.getMetaData().getColumnName(i).contains("ДАТА"))) {
try {
    Date parsedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse(rst.getString(i));
} catch (ParseException ex) {
…
}
row.add(parsedDate);
} else {
       row.add(rst.getObject(i));
}
```

В JTable получаю:  Wed Dec 14 00:00:00 MSK 1938

Comment: Вы зря 2 раза конвертируете даты. Сначала в оракле преобразуете дату в строку, а на стороне клиента наоборот. 

p.s. к сожалению плохо знаком с Jtable, но думаю что вам надо подставлять реальные значения даты прямо в таблицу. И date форматтер (возможно не для ячейки? а для столбца) который бы отображал дату в нужном формате

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читайте из Oracle в родном формате даты

```
select date from table
```

Далее при чтении JDBC читайте его как через `Resultset.getDate()` или `Resultset.getTime()` или `Resultset.getTimestamp()` (в зависимости от хотелок) в итоге получите нормальный `Date` объект.